# Sending data using Ajax to local PHP script, receive response but if-condition in php file is never met

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a draggable div-container and whenever I drop it, its location is to be send to a local php script.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#fenster" ).draggable({
        stack: "#fenster", stop: function(event, ui){
            var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
            var pos_y = ui.offset.top;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: {'x': pos_x},
                url: "index.php",
            }).done(function(msg){
                alert("data Saved: " + msg);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the php file (index.php) I check whether $_POST['x'] is set. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, the condition is never met.

```
  if((isset($_POST['x']))){
    $_SESSION['xLoc'] = $_POST['x'];
    echo "Test";
  }
```

Upon dropping the window, I get a response (alert of the msg shows output) and according to FireBug, the request DOES contain x.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, file_get_contents('php://input'))`. see what's arriving at the server. but note that since you're telling jquery to use `application/json` as the type to send to the server, PHP may be IGNORING the data parameter since you aren't sending a app/x-www-form or multi-part/form-data, which means reading directly from php://input will be your only way to retrieve that data.

Comment: array(0) { } string(0) ""  is outputted.

Comment: there you go. no post data is reaching the server at all. `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` will probably show it's hitting the server as GET, which means you've got a rewrite/redirect killing your post.

Comment: @NL3 My answer below should work for you.  Simply remove contentType from your jquery.

Comment: This could very well be since I have a couple of conditional redirects in the file. However, they are only executed under certain circumstances and PHP should actually "execute" the if-condition I posted above first before executing the lines coming after.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you were right. I had two redirects that were being executed due to a lack of an additional condition within the if-condition. It is now executing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two redirects that killed the POST request. After making adjustments to the if-conditions, this no longer happens and the data sent by the Ajax request is now also being successfully processed by PHP.

Thank you all that took the time to help me, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP superglobal $_POST, is only available when you use these content types

```
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded (standard content type for simple form-posts) or
    multipart/form-data-encoded (mostly used for file uploads)
```

You are using application/json which means you need to get the stream with...

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$d = json_decode($rawData);
if((isset($d['x']))){
  $_SESSION['xLoc'] = $d['x'];
  echo "Test";
}
```

Or if you dont actually need to be submitting JSON, just remove the contentType from your jquery, and you should be able to retrieve the $_POST on the php side,  using the code you already had.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {'x': pos_x},
    url: "index.php",
}).done(function(msg){
   alert("data Saved: " + msg);
 });
```

Or change your php to the code above, to retrieve the raw stream, if you need to be sending json data to the server

Comment: "You are using application/json which means you need to get the stream with" — That would be true if what was being sent was actually JSON, but it isn't, so `json_decode` will fail.

Comment: Thats besides the point.  He's asking why his $_POST variable is empty.  Thats the reason why.  If he removes contentType from the jquery, it will work

Comment: *"Thats besides the point"* — It isn't, because you have provided some code which uses `json_decode` which you say will fix the problem. *"If he removes contentType from the jquery, it will work"* — That is true, but you've presented it as an alternative to the first set of code and not as the only working solution in your answer.

Comment: The if-condition is still not met, unfortunately.

Comment: leave your php how it was, remove contentType. Does that work?  Also...is ui.offset.left defined?  Perhaps you are not actually sending any data?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. When I look at the POST parameters with FireBug, I see that x indeed has a value set (a valid one).